# Where is EJB3PersistEventListener in Hibernate 4.3.10?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, wildfly-8

While trying to upgrade a project based on a rather old JBoss/Hibernate version to Wildfly, I wasn't able to find the class

```
org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener
```

in 4.3.10 version of Hibernate.

I supposed those classes have been removed - but I didn't find any info how events can be implemented now. Or am I just missing the correct Maven import?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find anything about this class being deprecated or anything like this.

You should checkout if DefaultPersistOnFlushEventListener of Hibernate Core can help you to upgrade.

[Here's the documentation of DefaultPersistOnFlushEventListener](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/event/def/DefaultPersistOnFlushEventListener.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was also hoping for a note on deprecration and a hint how to migrate existing code. Your class is a nice find - I have to wait until we have the time to try it out, though, because it looks like a bigger change..

Comment: I see... Have a good luck then, let us know if anything foes not work as intended during your upgrade, thanks!